# jquery selector to choose a different element than the one clicked

Tags: jquery

This is the simplified html:

```
<div id="l01">
<ul style="width:450px;">
<li><img src="images/iconarrow.gif" alt="arrow" width="9" height="11" align="left" />&nbsp;
<a href="#">Preview</a>                            
</li>

<li class="showStats"><a class="showstatlink" href="javascript:{}"><img class="sstatsImage" src="images/iconarrow.gif"  />&nbsp;
                        Show Stats</a>                            
</li>                         
</ul>                       
</div>
<div class="sstatsDetails">
        ...
</div>
```

I want to click on class='showstatlink', and i want that click to trigger a toggle of class='sstatsDetails', but only the next one, I don't want all of the elements on the page with that class to toggle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".showstatlink").click(function() {
    // Your code to handle the event.
    $(".sstatsDetails").show();  // Or hide whatever you want to do.
});
```

Comment: No, because that will show all of the other elements on the page with class sstatDetails.  I want only the next one down.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$(".showstatlink").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().next(".sstatsDetails").toggle();
});
```

You can see it in action [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/qZkzg/1/)